# linux : listing files that contain several words

Tags: linux, grep

I try to find a way to list all the files in the directory tree (recursively) that contain several words.

While searching I found example such as `egrep -R -l 'toto|tata' .` but | induce OR. I would like AND...

Thank you for your help

Comment: `find . -name '*toto*' -a -name '*tata*'`?

Comment: @myaut: I guess OP wants the pattern in file contents and not file-name/

Comment: Do the files have to contain the words in a certain order? Or just contain the words? I have a script that can do that, although I don't think that it's recursive. It could be modified.

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output. Include potential partial-match cases like `ratata` and `tototata` so we can see if they should be considered a match or not.

Comment: I have a bash script that will do this and more. The only shortcoming is that it is not recursive and that it will not handle file names containing spaces. Is there any way to upload whole files? It's very cumbersome to copy them into the answer box with four leading spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Using `GNU grep` with `GNU xargs`,

```
grep -ERl 'toto' | xargs -r grep 'tata'
```

The first `grep` lists those files containing the pattern `toto` which is then fed to `xargs` and with the second `grep` those files containing `tata` is retrieved. The `-r` flag is to ensure second `grep` doesn't run on an empty output.

The `-r` flag in `xargs` from the `man` page,

```
-r, --no-run-if-empty
       If the standard input does not contain any nonblanks, do not run the command.  
       Normally, the command is run once even if there is  no  input. This option is a GNU 
       extension.
```

Comment: Shouldn't second `grep` also have `-l`?

Comment: @myaut: That wasn't quite clear from `OP`'s post, BTW, he could add it if needed!

Comment: I think that this will work as long as the filenames do not contain a space.

Answer (score 1):

`agrep` tool is designed for providing AND to grep with usage:

```
 agrep 'pattern1;pattern2' file
```

In your case you could run

```
find . -type f -exec agrep 'toto;tata' {} \; #apply -l to display the file names
```

PS1: For current directory you can just `agrep 'pattern1;pattern2' *.*`
PS2: Unfortunatelly agrep does not support -R option.

Comment: s/Unfortunately/Fortunately/ but in reality `agrep` isn't useful for this since you can always do `awk '/pattern1/&&/pattern2/'` on any UNIX system.